# karate-gatling: how to force a sequential execution of all existing feature files in parallel even if one of them fails?

Tags: karate

Currently I have a `workflow.feature` for a gatling performance test, that calls all existing functional tests in the given order. If one of the tests breaks the whole workflow is stopped.

**How to force the execution of all steps even if one step fails?**

```
Feature: A workflow of all functional tests to be executed for performance/loading tests.

  Scenario: Test all functional scenarios in the given order.
    * call read('classpath:foo1/bar1.feature')
    * call read('classpath:foo2/bar2.feature')
    * call read('classpath:foo3/bar3.feature')
    ...
    * call read('classpath:fooX/barX.feature')
```

This is a manually managed list of calls, but **maybe there is a way to grab all existing feature files from all subfolders dynamically**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If one of the tests breaks the whole workflow is stopped.

If you use a `Scenario Outline:` it processes all rows even if one fails. So maybe:

```
Scenario Outline:

call read('classpath:' + file)

Examples:
| file            |
| foo/bar.feature |
| baz/ban.feature |
```

> maybe there is a dynamic way to grab all existing feature files from all subfolders

You should be able to write Scala code to do this if you insist and this has nothing to do with Karate. Or the above dynamic feature may give you some ideas. Hint - you can mix Java into Karate feature files very easily.

> Is there a way to force the execution of a list of features in any order so, that the next feature file is executed if the previous one is failed.

See above. Also don't ask so many questions in one, keep it simple please.